# Linux development/minimal smtp and pop3 server

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, linux, email

I use python based as well as rails applications on ubuntu linux. We have functionalities like register, forgot password, reset password, email alerts etc features based on emails. Since now a days, we go on offline development, we want to run a local smtp & pop3 server to send and receive emails.

Emails shall be send via the our web application and we will use the email clients like thunderbird to receive emails(just to verify).

I have used jmailsrv (I have used 6 years ago, but could not locate exact package now), a java based simple email server. Are there any other light alternative for development work?

Comment: Does this belong on SuperUser?

Comment: I don't think that super user community shall use any tiny email servers. This is more developer oriented question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why does it need to be a simple mail server?
Can't you just use something like postfix which is very easy for simple configurations

Comment: simple email server means easy to maintain, less resource intensive, more over easy to configure. Postfix required a pop3 companion, am I right?

Comment: @Gopalakrishnan Subramani: Postfix can deliver local mail to your application directly or via http://www.procmail.org/ which can do just about anything.  If you *really* want to check mail with Thunderbird (why?), it does understand mbox and maildir formats natively.  There's no need for POP3 anywhere.